# how to access spark history server from DSX?

Tags: data-science-experience

I need to access the Spark History Server so that I performance tune a slow spark job.

I was looking for a link within DSX but could not find one, so I have opened up the spark service in the Bluemix console and have navigated to the spark history server directly from there (Job History link) .

Is there a way to access the spark history server directly from DSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have to access the spark history server by logging in to the Bluemix console as I have been doing.

There is a feature request here asking to make this process much more integrated:  https://datascix.uservoice.com/forums/387207-general/suggestions/17707459-give-access-to-spark-ui-to-monitor-jobs-without-ha - please vote for this!